# react deployment is failing in aws-amplify, but it is working in netlify and vercel

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, deployment, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy my React app to amplify but it is failing on npm run build,
I have tried to deploy to netlify and vercel, everything is working correctly there

here is the build log

```
2022-04-21T22:49:30.401Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci
2022-04-21T22:49:46.268Z [INFO]: > node-sass@7.0.1 install /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/node-sass
                                 > node scripts/install.js
2022-04-21T22:49:48.208Z [INFO]: Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v7.0.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
2022-04-21T22:49:48.400Z [INFO]: Download complete
2022-04-21T22:49:48.402Z [INFO]: Binary saved to /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
2022-04-21T22:49:48.454Z [INFO]: Caching binary to /root/.npm/_cacache/node-sass/7.0.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
2022-04-21T22:49:48.470Z [INFO]: > node-sass@7.0.1 postinstall /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/node-sass
                                 > node scripts/build.js
2022-04-21T22:49:48.641Z [INFO]: Binary found at /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
2022-04-21T22:49:48.641Z [INFO]: Testing binary
2022-04-21T22:49:48.782Z [INFO]: Binary is fine
2022-04-21T22:49:48.806Z [INFO]: > core-js-pure@3.22.2 postinstall /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/core-js-pure
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2022-04-21T22:49:48.849Z [INFO]: [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
                                 [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js:[0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://patreon.com/zloirock [0m
                                 [96m>[94m bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz [0m
                                 [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
2022-04-21T22:49:48.871Z [INFO]: > @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@6.1.1 postinstall /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types
                                 > node attribution.js
2022-04-21T22:49:48.910Z [INFO]: Font Awesome Free 6.1.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
                                 License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
                                 Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc.
2022-04-21T22:49:48.915Z [INFO]: > @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@6.1.1 postinstall /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
                                 > node attribution.js
2022-04-21T22:49:48.954Z [INFO]: Font Awesome Free 6.1.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
                                 License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
                                 Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc.
2022-04-21T22:49:49.187Z [INFO]: > core-js@3.22.2 postinstall /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest/node_modules/core-js
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2022-04-21T22:49:49.467Z [INFO]: added 1577 packages in 17.937s
2022-04-21T22:49:49.481Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2022-04-21T22:49:49.482Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2022-04-21T22:49:49.644Z [INFO]: > supplierportal_web@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src033897583/src/ReconGuideAwsAmplifyTest
                                 > react-scripts build
2022-04-21T22:49:50.771Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2022-04-21T22:50:06.489Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
```

amplify build settings

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I've tried to delete node_modules and package-lock.json locally then reinstalling, still failing.
npm run build is working locally
I am stuck on this for 10 hours pls save me

Comment: I am getting the same problem with this. Have you got any solutions?

Comment: @CarlAngeloAngcana sorry for late reply, In case you haven't solved it yet, it was a problem with AWS settings where you need to manually change the node.js version to the latest version (or the version you are using)

Comment: @eksoo bro you are amazing that's what worked for me so dumb that the error message didn't say this.